# CPU resources not allocated proportionally to Docker `cpu-shares`

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

#### Summary

CPU resources are **sometimes** not allocated proportionally to Docker's `cpu-shares` if some containers run more processes than others.

#### (Reproducible) Example

I want to allocate CPU resources equally to two docker containers. To do this, I pass the same `cpu-shares` value to both containers. The following commands run a CPU stress tool to use as much CPU as they can. The container `single-stress` runs only 1 stress client, while `multi-stress` runs only 8 stress clients.

```sh
docker run -d --rm -it --name="single-stress" --cpu-shares=512 --cpuset-cpus="0" progrium/stress --cpu 1 --timeout 30s
docker run -d --rm -it --name="multi-stress" --cpu-shares=512 --cpuset-cpus="0" progrium/stress --cpu 8 --timeout 30s
docker stats
```

I expect the CPU utilization of both containers to be about 50%. Yet the results of `docker stats` show that this is not the case.

```sh
CONTAINER ID   NAME            CPU %  
ed8e2794d415   multi-stress    62.52%
27ac7a1fc8c9   single-stress   38.07%
```

The container that runs more stress clients receives more than 60% of the CPU for the entire duration of the experiment.

- Is this behavior expected? Are containers that run a larger number of processes more likely to receive more CPU resources according to Linux's cgroups and CFS scheduler?
- Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

#### How often does this erroneous behavior occur?

The erroneous behavior does not always happen and thus may not be instantly reproducible for readers. I have tested the aforementioned example on different machines (see information about machines further down the page). Here are the results:

| Machine | Probability of "Erroneous" Behavior* |
| --- | --- |
| A | 95% |
| B | 30% |
| C | 5% |

* Behavior is considered "erroneous" if the container `multi-stress` receives more than 60% CPU for the entire duration of the experiment.

Machine description:

- Machine A:

  - Local PC
  - ```sh
    # docker info
    Cgroup Driver: systemd
    Cgroup Version: 1
    Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc runsc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Security Options:
    Kernel Version: 5.8.0-53-generic
    Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    ```
- Machine B:

  - Google Cloud VM
  - ```sh
    # docker info
    Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
    Cgroup Version: 1
    Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Kernel Version: 5.8.0-050800-generic  # Similar results with kernel 5.4.0-1043-gcp
    Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    ```
- Machine C:

  - Local laptop
  - ```sh
    Cgroup Driver: systemd
    Cgroup Version: 1
    Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Kernel Version: 5.4.0-73-generic
    Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    ```